# How to disable replacement of text characters with their graphic representation while printing PDF file?

Tags: pdf, text, printing

I have virtual printer driver which creates EMF files from printed stuff. After that my application analyses created EMF files and extracts text information.
Here is the problem: often if customer prints PDF file text information is missing in generated EMF file because PDF printing software replaces non-ascii characters with their graphic representation. For example instead one of EMR_EXTTEXTOUT/EMR_SMALLTEXTOUT records generated file contains EMR_BEGINPATH/EMR_POLYDRAW16/EMR_ENDPATH sequence for every printed character. So i am unable to extract text information from such EMF file.
Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do, this behavior is implemented in the printing software or in the PDF file itself (the PDF file might contain text as curves and not as plain text), not in the print driver. 
Perhaps the printing software has an option to switch between text as text printing and text as curves printing.

Comment: I am sure that my test PDF contains text as text (not curves). I checked that with third-party text extracting utilities.

Comment: @igor.sol - in this situation the problem is with the printing software.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not found such option (text-as-text/text-as-curves) in any printing software.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is nothing you can do.

Comment: can you suggest any tool which will drop any embedded fonts from PDF file and replace them with fonts existing in my windows system?

Comment: I do not know such a tool, but it will not help with your problem. It is not the font, it is the printing application that parses the fonts and renders the text as lines and curves instead of rendering it as text.

Comment: From my observations it is font. I forget to say that not all the text is replaced by lines and curves in output. For example if i print PDF document containing english and greek text then only greek  text is converted to lines and curves.

Comment: On the other side i found printing tool (http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/pdf-printer-print-pdfa.aspx) which has option to "Convert embedded OpenType fonts to Type1 fonts (PostScript fonts)". When i print original PDF file using this option no text is converted to lines curves. So my guess is if source PDF will not contain embedded OpenType fonts then it will be printed without text-to-curves conversion in most standard printing software.